# suggest search phrase based on inputted keyword

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

user can search keyword in my app and I want to suggest some phrases to him, which contain that keyword (generally like google). what I currently do is:

```
1. searching for the rows which contain the keyword
2. then select the keyword and also 2 words after the spotted keyword as a suggestion phrase 
(for example if the searched keyword is "blue", and the text in the row is "blue shirt and jeans",
I select "blue shirt and" as a suggestion phrase)
3. select the 5 most repeated phrases as suggestion phrases
```

while this is a quick and generally meaningful solution, I'm looking for a better one. can I implement a pure `SQL` solution which suggests better results? or it definitely needs machine learning to get better suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure out an answer to your question above? I'm trying to do something similar so would be quite helpful if you already have a solution.

Comment: @Chipmunk_da I wanted to implement such search suggestion algorithm for my shopping application, so finally decided to generate suggestion keywords based on "products categories and subcategories" which I already have in my database. so now when you type for example "pants", it recommends you "pants type A", "pants type B" and etc! not sure if it makes sense in your scenario though!